Flutter Как открыть приложение через URI схему
Подскажите пожалуйста как в приложении flutter запустить приложение сбербанка. Я использую подход через URI схему String sberbankUrlSchemeLogin = 'sberbankonline://'; Приложение пытается открыться видно логотип Сбербанка но пишет что такой ссылки не существует и выкидывает.

Вы вообще что сделать пытаетесь с приложением Сбера? Если просто открыть, то это не лучший способ.

Да, нужно просто открыть. Пробовал через AppDevice но работает только для Android

можно запустить по имени пакета. Надо только посмотреть его название для Сбера. Предполагаю, что начало имени пакета там ru.sberbank для надёжности лучше использовать полное пространство имени их мобильного приложения.

А для IOS как открыть приложение?

А да) точно вопрос не про чистый андроид, а про flutter. Ну тогда это наверное где-то здесь можно найти -https://developers.sber.ru

Чтобы была поддержка и ios, и android, есть только такой способ:
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

Future<void> openSberbank() async {
  final Uri url = Uri.parse('sberbankonline://');

  try {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      await _openSberbankWeb();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Обработайте ошибку, например, покажите сообщение пользователю.
    print('Ошибка при открытии Сбербанк Онлайн: $e');
  }
}

Future<void> _openSberbankWeb() async {
  final Uri url = Uri.parse('https://online.sberbank.ru');

  try {
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      // Обработайте ошибку, например, покажите сообщение пользователю.
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Обработайте ошибку, например, покажите сообщение пользователю.
    print('Ошибка при открытии Сбербанк Онлайн: $e');
  }
}

Но нужно учитывать что у сбера есть разные URI-схемы и обычно после // должно быть что-то ещё:
sber://
sberbankonline://
sbolonline://
ru.sberbankmobile://

